# Creating a method that asks for input within a range and returns that value

Tags: java, methods, return

I need to make a method based on the instructions below. The prompt is "What width would you like?". The user enters input, and if it is not an integer between 3 and 20, the error message "Expected a number between 3 and 20" pops up. The user is supposed to continue typing input until a valid answer is given, and then that value should be returned to main.

This method prompts the user for a number, verifies that it is between min and max, inclusive, before returning the number.

If the number entered is not between min and max then the user is shown an error message and given another opportunity to enter a number. If min is 1 and max is 5 the error message is: "Expected a number from 1 to 5."

If the user enters characters, words or anything other than a valid int then the user is shown the same message.  The entering of characters other than a valid int is detected using Scanner's methods (hasNextInt) and does not use exception handling.

Do not use constants in this method, only use the min and max passed in parameters for all comparisons and messages. Do not create an instance of Scanner in this method, pass the reference to the Scanner in main, to this method. The entire prompt should be passed in and printed out.

```
/**
 *@param in  The reference to the instance of Scanner created in main.
 *@param prompt  The text prompt that is shown once to the user.
 *@param min  The minimum value that the user must enter.
 *@param max  The maximum value that the user must enter.
 *@return The integer that the user entered that is between min and max, inclusive.
 */
public static int promptUser(Scanner in, String prompt, int min, int max) {
}
```

Comment: Make a good faith effort to solve the problem and post your code, then we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but it should be:

```
public static int promptUser(Scanner in, String prompt, int min, int max)
{
    System.out.println(prompt);
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            String val = in.next();
            int value = Integer.parseInt(val);
            if (min > value || max < value)
                throw new Exception();
            else
            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Expected a number between " + min + " and " + max);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I make sure the error message pops up if the input is anything but an integer between 3 and 20. For example, they enter "bananas" or "hello everyone" or "2".

Comment: I edited my answer. It will show `Expected a number between min and max` for any invalid input.

Answer (score -1):

For simplicity's sake, I use EasyReader not scanner. But here's some concepts that you may want to use (this looks like an assignment of some sort).

First I just made an EasyReader that would read ints.

In the pvsm I made two inputs that take up user input. **You may also want to consider making a sorting array so the user doesn't need to find the lowest val.**

Boolean's are ...

```
public static int promptUser(EasyReader in, int min, int max){
    while(true){
        //idk what prompt is but ere u go.
        System.out.print("Enter a num between "+min+" and "+max+" ");
        in = new EasyReader();
        int take = in.readInt();
        if(take == min || take == max){
            System.out.print(take);
            return take;
        }
        else if(take >= min && take <= max){
            System.out.print(take);
            return take;
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Error ... bannanas! ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `EasyReader`?

Comment: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/05wi/MazeRunnersProject/easyreader_doc.htm